# Get a json object from the url while using facebook graph api in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

how to get the JSON object through URL in my ruby on rails code:

```
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXX"
```

I am not able to get good tutorial for JSON + Ruby on rails. 
Can someone help me out thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

json_object = JSON.parse(open("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=XXX").read)
```

This is the simplest way, though it may not be the fastest.

Edit: If the URI contains special characters in its parameter string, it has to be escaped/encoded with `URI.escape` first.

Comment: open-uri is a gem ? i could find openurl

Comment: open-uri is part of the ruby standard library

Comment: we have to do a URI.encode(URL) on the URL, then it will work .. thanks I got the answer. I deleted the token :-)

Comment: the problem is ruby cannot deal with the special token in the URL so we have to do a URI.encode.. probably you can edit your answer. thanks anyway.

Comment: Why not using CGI.escape, since URI is deprecated?